# Eigenvalues of $L^\dagger L$ are positive

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $L$ be a linear operator on a complex vector space $V$, how to show that eigenvalues of $L^\dagger L$ are positive? I guess this might be a statement taught in a functional analysis class or an advanced linear algebra class?

Comment: Is $\dagger$ the same Hermitian?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Right.

Comment: Is $V$ a Hilbert space? And is $L$ a bounded linear operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property "self-adjoint" is only defined for operators on inner product spaces.

Now suppose that $V$ is an inner product space with inner product $( \cdot, \cdot)$.

Then we have for $u,v \in V: (L^\dagger Lu,v)=(Lu,Lv)=(u, L^\dagger Lv).$ This shows that $L^\dagger L$ is selfadjoint.

If $ \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $L^\dagger L$, then there is $u \in V$ with $L^\dagger Lu = \mu u$. Thus

$ \mu (u,u)=( \mu u,u)= (L^\dagger Lu,u)=(Lu,Lu).$

This gives $ \mu \ge 0$.

Comment: I think you mean "this shows that $L^{\dagger}L$ is self-adjoint".

Comment: Could you please explain where the self-adjointness of $L^\dagger L$ was used? Since $\mu=\|Lu\|^2/\|u\|^2$, do we also have that $\mu>0$?

Answer (score 0):

Using the singular value decomposition (SVD) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

we have $$L=UDV\to L^\dagger =V^\dagger D^\dagger U^\dagger$$therefore $$L^\dagger L=V^\dagger D^\dagger D V$$since $V$ is unitary, the eigenvalues of $L\dagger L$ are the same as $D^\dagger D$ and since $D^\dagger D$ is diagonal positive semi definite, the proof is complete.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Characterizations Here is a proof which shows that the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are positive, but what if the space $V$ is of infinite dimension?

Comment: It matters not since $v^\dagger L^\dagger Lv=|Lv|^2\ge 0$....