# Proving that the adjoint of a general linear operator times said operator is a Hermitian on a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

With L being a linear operator on a complex vector space $V$ show that $L^{_\dagger}L$ is Hermitian with non negative eigenvalues

I don't really have much of an idea how to do this exercise in such a general example. The proof of non negative eigenvalues is especially eluding me. Any ideas?

Comment: Use $(v,L^{\dagger} Lv)=(Lv,Lv)=\|Lv\|^2$.

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018591/eigenvalues-of-l-dagger-l-are-positive/3018600#3018600